# MangoPay error on adding bank account to a mango user

Tags: payment

I am using the MangoPay php sdk to create a bank account for a user on mango pay, here the code

```
$api = new \MangoPay\MangoPayApi();     
$api->Config->ClientId = 'clientid';
$api->Config->ClientPassword = 'password';
$api->Config->TemporaryFolder = 'temp/mango/';
$mango_user_id = '1234567';

$bank_account = new \MangoPay\BankAccount();
$details = new \MangoPay\BankAccountDetailsIBAN();
$details->IBAN = 'ibanbannkaccountnumber';
$details->BIC  = 'CRLYFRPP';

$bank_account->OwnerName = 'Joe Blogs'; 
$bank_account->Details = $details;
$created_account = $api->Users->CreateBankAccount($mango_user_id,$bank_account);
```

and getting this error message:

ResponseException in RestTool.php line 345:
Bad request. One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.

Comment: So you have the explaiation of error and possible cause in error message. What else you want us to do?

Comment: Don't you have to fill the OwnerAddress too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mangopay.com/endpoints/v2.01/bank-accounts#e41_create-an-iban-bankaccount

OwnerAddress is required

```
$bank_account->OwnerAddress = new \MangoPay\Address();
$bank_account->OwnerAddress->AddressLine1 = 'addressLine1';
$bank_account->OwnerAddress->City = 'city';
$bank_account->OwnerAddress->PostalCode = 'PostalCode';
$bank_account->OwnerAddress->Country = 'CountryIsoCode';
```